# Geoserver looks for qix file for image pyramid

Tags: geoserver

The latest geoserver (2.17.1) with extension imagepyramid is looking for *.qix file for each request. I don't have any trouble in the old version (2.8.0) with the same dataset.

The error message is

```
26 Jun 16:55:15 ERROR [data.shapefile] -/2/2.qix (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /2/2.qix (Permission denied)
```

The pyramid retile files are generated by gdal package. Any suggestions I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.qix` file](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/data/shapefile/files/ShpFileType.html#QIX) is an open version of the shape index (`shx`) file that speeds up access to the shapefile (but ESRI in their wisdom didn't open that part of the format).

To fix this you need to make sure the user running GeoServer can write to the pyramid directory (this is good practice anyway). If you really don't want to allow GeoServer to create this file then you could do it by opening all the shapefiles in QGIS as a user that does have write access to that directory.